# Unable to see device and events log in DebugView

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to setup analytics with **firebase** on my **react native app**.

I have tried mutiples solutions from different forum like *StackOverflow* or *Github*.
Here's what I put in my code :

```
import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';

analytics().logEvent('TEST_EVENT');
```

And here's the solutions I try :

- In `GoogleService-Info` make **IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED** become **true** instead of **false**
- Used the following command to see my events in the debug view:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app .none.        //disable
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app [app_name]    //enable
```

- See the logs with the following commands:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

- And here's my logs :

```
09-08 18:21:23.401 V/FA      (26224): Connecting to remote service
09-08 18:21:23.456 D/FA      (26224): Connected to remote service
09-08 18:21:23.457 V/FA      (26224): Processing queued up service tasks: 1
09-08 18:21:23.469 V/FA-SVC  ( 3653): Logging event: origin=app,name=TEST_EVENT,params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=app, ga_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-8052166940190804487}]
09-08 18:21:23.488 V/FA-SVC  ( 3653): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 500
09-08 18:21:23.489 V/FA-SVC  ( 3653): Unscheduling upload
09-08 18:21:23.490 V/FA-SVC  ( 3653): Scheduling upload, millis: 500
09-08 18:21:23.492 V/FA-SVC  ( 3653): Background event processing time, ms: 24

(...) " Bunch of informations, i don\'t want this to be too long. " (...)

09-08 18:21:39.578 V/FA      (32176): Connecting to remote service
09-08 18:21:39.610 V/FA      (32176): Connection attempt already in progress
09-08 18:21:39.620 V/FA      (32176): Connection attempt already in progress
09-08 18:21:39.620 D/FA      (32176): Setting app measurement enabled (FE): true
09-08 18:21:39.621 D/FA      (32176): Updating Scion state (FE)
09-08 18:21:39.637 V/FA      (32176): Connection attempt already in progress
09-08 18:21:39.637 D/FA      (32176): Connected to remote service
09-08 18:21:39.637 V/FA      (32176): Processing queued up service tasks: 4
09-08 18:21:39.654 V/FA-SVC  ( 3653): Saving default event parameters, appId, data size: com.google.android.youtube, 2
09-08 18:21:44.657 V/FA      (32176): Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

I'm sure it's not a problem from my phone bc when I run `./adb devices`
I can see my phone:

```
List of devices attached
MUN0219130000631        device
```

Even on the side of **Firebase**, i got the firebase authentification and real-time database which works very well.

But in debug View console, I am unable to see the logs or even device available.
[Firebase screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13692458/28303202-7c2e6938-6baf-11e7-8dc3-7acc469924bf.png)

Thanks in advance for your time !
*p.s: It's my first post on StackOverflow, be kind and let me know if i can do it better next time*

Comment: Did you managed to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not yet